# GDB printing inconsistent size with large static array

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm seeing the following issue with GDB (GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3) 8.1.0.20180409-git) printing the size of a large, statically-allocated, fixed-size array:

```
(gdb) p &buf
$1 = (char (*)[52428800000]) 0x15491f84e000 <buf>
(gdb) p sizeof(buf)
$2 = 889192448
```

I also tried `printf("%ld", sizeof(buf));` in the corresponding C++ program, which prints `52428800000` as I would expect.

Is this behavior expected? What is the smaller value GDB is printing?

Comment: You got a 50gb `char` array declared? Impressive. How much GB of RAM is in your machine?

Comment: Around 63G (ec2 m4.4xlarge). Though you can declare a large static array backed by virtual memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out just after posting --  it seems the issue is that gdb defaults to int32 outputs for sizeof -- `printf("%d", sizeof(buf))` prints  889192448. I'll look into filing a bug report.